# Dragging a clone after making it resizable with jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Having a little trouble making a clone both draggable and resizable:

This piece of code makes the clone draggable (The addClass is related to something else within the program.)

```
if(ui.draggable[0].id){
$(this)
.append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable().addClass("resize"));
```

I tried the following, but then the clone vanishes when dropped:

```
if(ui.draggable[0].id){
$(this)
.append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable().resizable().addClass("resize"));
```

Here is my testing page.  Try dragging one of the characters.  Once on the comic strip, they shouild be resizable.  I also tried using addclass to make them resizable after drop, and then called a bit of jquery to make all items with that class resizable, and that worked as far as resizing, but dragging stopped working (and it seemed clunky):

http://www.thelionscall.com/wp-content/comic-creator/

Comment: Kristi, Cool webapp! When I drag a character on the strip, it does not become resizable... Is this your error? Or is it something else? From your question, it seems like the problem is something else.

Comment: My attempt to make it resizable made it non-draggable, so I took it back out.  It looked like:  if(ui.draggable[0].id){
$(this)
.append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable().resizable().addClass("resize resizable"));  $(".resizable").resizable();

It's adding the resizable syntax to that element alongside the draggable I seem to be having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

This is turning out to be a very tricky question...

I've come somewhere, though. Want to check it out?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    #mainImg {
        position: absolute !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mainImg").draggable();
        $("#mainImg").on('dragstop', function(event) { 
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).resizable();
            $(this).draggable();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <img style="width: 700px;" src="test.png" id="mainImg" class="ui-widget-content" alt="Test Image">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```